# TYPO3 9, assign form validation errors to the corresponding field

Tags: validation, error-handling, typo3, fluid, extbase

Normally TYPO3 assigns a variable in FrontEnd with the name `validationResults` and it looks like that.

[image: Errors]

Then we have to iterate through the Error objects and get a list with all the errors and their messages. But there is no way to take each one individually and assign it on the corresponding field where the error appears.

So the question is, how do i do it?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

After some programming and a help from larry-pete (typo3.slack.com) i found a solution.

**I created my own ViewHelper** and it looks like this:

**ext_localconf.php**

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['fluid']['namespaces']['mytag'][] = 'Vendor\\ExtensionName\\ViewHelpers';
```

**Classes/ViewHelpers/Form/ErrorViewHelper.php**

```
namespace Vendor\ExtensionName\ViewHelpers\Form;

use TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContextInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Form\AbstractFormFieldViewHelper;


class ErrorViewHelper extends AbstractFormFieldViewHelper
{
  use CompileWithRenderStatic;

  /**
  * As this ViewHelper renders HTML, the output must not be escaped.
  *
  * @var bool
  */
  protected $escapeOutput = false;

  public function initializeArguments()
 {
    $this->registerArgument('for', 'string', 'The name of the error name (e.g. argument name or property name). This can also be a property path (like blog.title), and will then only display the validation errors of that property.', false, '');
    $this->registerArgument('as', 'string', '', false, 'flattenedErrors');
 }


 /**
 * @param array $arguments
 * @param \Closure $renderChildrenClosure
 * @param RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext
 * @return mixed
 */
 public static function renderStatic(array $arguments, \Closure $renderChildrenClosure, RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext)
 {
    $as = $arguments['as'];
    $for = $arguments['for'];

    $templateVariableContainer = $renderingContext->getVariableProvider();
    $controllerContext = $renderingContext->getcontrollerContext();
    $validationResults = $controllerContext->getRequest()->getOriginalRequestMappingResults();

    if ($validationResults !== null){
        $validationResults = $validationResults->forProperty($for);
    }
    $flattenedErrors = $validationResults->getErrors();

    $output = $renderChildrenClosure();
    $withKeys = [];
    if (empty($output)) {
        if ($flattenedErrors) {
            foreach ($flattenedErrors as $error) {
                $withKeys[$error->getTitle()] = $error;
            }
        }
    }
    $templateVariableContainer->add($as, $withKeys);

    return $output;
 }
}
```

**Form.html**

```
<mytag:form.error as="error" for="error"/>
```

And this returns:

[image: Results]

So now, you can do something like that:

```
<f:if condition="{offer.firstName}"><span style="display: block">{offer.firstName.message}</span></f:if>
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I changed your Viewhelper a bit because it didn't worked in my version (typo3 9)

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\ViewHelpers;

use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContextInterface;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Traits\CompileWithRenderStatic;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;


class ErrorViewHelper extends AbstractViewHelper
{
  use CompileWithRenderStatic;

  /**
   * As this ViewHelper renders HTML, the output must not be escaped.
   *
   * @var bool
   */
  protected $escapeOutput = false;

  public function initializeArguments()
  {
    $this->registerArgument('for', 'string', 'The name of the error name (e.g. argument name or property name). This can also be a property path (like blog.title), and will then only display the validation errors of that property.', false, '');
  }


  /**
   * @param array $arguments
   * @param \Closure $renderChildrenClosure
   * @param RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext
   * @return mixed
   */
  public static function renderStatic(
    array $arguments,
    \Closure $renderChildrenClosure,
    RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext
  ) {
    $for = $arguments['for'];

    $controllerContext = $renderingContext->getControllerContext();
    $validationResults = $controllerContext->getRequest()->getOriginalRequestMappingResults();

    if ($validationResults !== null) {
      $validationResults = $validationResults->forProperty($for);
    }

    $flattenedErrors = $validationResults->getFlattenedErrors();
    return $flattenedErrors;
  }
}
```

you can do:

```
{myExt:error() -> f:variable(name: 'errors')}}
```

or

```
{ff:error( for:"user" ) -> f:variable(name: 'errors')}}
```